# Is there an energy balance of Supe's activities?

Tags: the-boys-2019, the-boys

In Season 3, Episode 2 of The Boys, A-Train says to Homelander that:

> He needs to eat 30,000 calories a day.  To which Homelander retorts
>  "only if you are actually running"

But given the energy output he would need to have to be the world's fastest man, that seems rather low.  For example, Michael Phelps ate up to about [10,000 calories per day](https://olympics.com/en/featured-news/michael-phelps-10000-calories-diet-what-the-american-swimmer-ate-while-training-) when he was in peak physical condition.

And given we have only barely (if ever) seen the A-Train eating anything, his statement also seems rather strange.

So has anyone done a reasonable estimation of the energy balance of any of the Supes?  EG how much energy does it take for the A-Train to run at top speed, or for Homelander to project his laser eyes (or even fly given his mass).

Or, are the Supes merely empty vessels and are simply channeling energy from some other source when they perform their super human feats?

Comment: This is a resonable question.  Remember, answers to questions like this have to be supported by statements within the story.

Comment: I guess they try to make it more grounded, but in general superhero stuff doesn't make sense from scientific point of view.

Comment: For ex. what would Homelander need to eat to travel like a jetplane? One cow per flight? ;D

Comment: @Mithoron: Only milk. He probably needs gallons of milk (from whatever source he can, apparently)